# Dismissing red frame in close up [Canon EOS M50]

Tags: canon, autofocus, focus, camera-settings, point-and-shoot

Is there a way to take a shot even though the red frame indicating out of focus appears?

When I am trying to take a picture few inches away from something the red frame appears. Someone asked similar question here:
[Why can't my dSLR take close-up photos?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/94113/why-cant-my-dslr-take-close-up-photos/94115)

I don't care about "shortest distance at which that lens can bring an object into focus" mentioned there. I just want to take a picture as is.

Comment: In which mode do you make photos: A, P, Av, Tv, M?

Comment: Usually switching to manual focus will disable any safeguard against taking misfocussed images.

Comment: @RomeoNinov I was trying to take a pic with every mode.

Comment: @KaiMattern Thanks, but still the red frame appears and I can't take a pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The manual is online but quite tedious to page through online so I don't have the absolute definitive answer but what you want to do is to be able to release the shutter without focus being achieved.
You might be able to do this by setting the camera to manual focus (pg 143) and trying a shot.
There are other issues with doing this, the lens body combination may not be able to focus as close as you wish and the subject may bee in varying degrees of focus (or out-of-focus) but you will have to work that out once you can get a shot from where you want.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for.